# Ionic Cordova Error When Build and Running

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have some error when I want to compile my ionic4 project app to my android phone. When I running "ionic Cordova run android", it shows me the error, so the app can't be running/installed on my phone. Please help me. thanks

This is the error code:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

> 1 actionable task: 1 executed
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Subproject Path: app
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:38)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:38)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
Cordova runs android exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: have you tried the `--verbose` flag?

Comment: yes, but i don't understand the error result too

Answer (score 4):

1.remove android platform using

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

2. remove manually `node-modules` and `package-lock.json` (imp*)
3. **Unistall** old Application
4. `npm cache clean --force`
5. Run `npm install`
6. Finally `ionic cordova run android`